# Exposing awrah to the ground when praying

Tags: salat, fiqh, clothing

As-salamu-alikum,

I just want to clarify that is it okay to pray when our awrah (privy parts of the body) is exposed to the ground? For example, wearing thope without an under garment/sarong wrap without under garment/similar scenarios

Comment: What part of the awrah are you exposing if it's already wrapped under clothes?

Comment: Wear jeans/tights if you are worried.

Comment: Then what about the situation of the past, when people at the time of Prophet (pbuh) also didn't have under garments to wear?

Answer (score 1):

As much as I searched concerning covering the Awrah during the Salah, I found a more general issue in regard to the mentioned matter that probably could be beneficial for you:

In case the person who is saying prayer doesn’t cover his Awrah, his salah is invalid…
Or he has quoted in another matter that “if the clothes covers the Awrah in the standing situation, but perhaps it doesn’t cover it in another situation such as Roku or Sojud, then in case that he covers it by something (when his Awrah is seeable), then his salah would be correct.
 (Ayatollah Sistani as a Shia Marja’ al Taqlid) { [www.sistani.org](http://www.sistani.org/persian/book/50/45/) }

It could be inferred from the Fatwas that the most important matter in the salah is related to the covering the Awrah that they don’t be seeable. Besides it could be inferred that the Awrah ought not be seeable from the angle of others. But anyway I reckon you’d better wear underpants for more precaution. (anyway, you’d better do more search about it to be confident).

---

**Reference(s):**

- [www.sistani.org](http://www.sistani.org/persian/book/50/45/)
- [farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-imam-content?id=341&tid=99)

Answer (score 1):

The point with awrah is that it shouldn't be exposed to others. If it was exposed to the ground and nobody could see it while you pray than everything is fine. See for example [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/ar/161722) in Arabic about if a woman can pray wearing only one garment (without underwear).

On the other hand one is allowed to pray with only one (single) garment via ahadith like [this one](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/11) from sahih al-Bukahri, which mentions the recommendation of covering the shoulders, as scholars say that this way one can secure that the garment wouldn't fall down and the awrah wouldn't be exposed to others (for details [see this](https://islamqa.info/en/125425) fatwa). An [other hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/13) makes clear that one could also tie the garment around the waist if it was too short (so covering shoulders is not mandatory). An other indication that the sahaba used to pray only in one garment is [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/14), which clearly indicates that the women would maybe see the awrah if they raised their heads sooner then described. See also [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/10) which may indicate that having more than one single garment is a matter of wealth. See also [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/191) and [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/malik/48) on the etiquette of dressing (one shouldn't expose his awrah) and [this on](http://sunnah.com/urn/730170) one shouldn't look at the awrah of somebody else.

To conclude it is permissible to pray exposing the awrah to the ground as long as you can assure that you won't expose it to somebody else! But on the other hand if one can avoid such a situation it would be much better an remember also ([7:31](http://legacy.quran.com/7/31))

> **O children of Adam, take your adornment at every masjid**, and eat and drink, but be not excessive. Indeed, He likes not those who commit excess.

Answer (score 0):

maybe,it won't require much hardship to pray with an undergarment such as trouser or shortpant covering the knee...It is prescribed to wear good cloths during salah as I know.

Answer (score -1):

generally yes because that is all said about covering against humans and maybe against some animals. there is a [weak narration](http://salaf-forum.com:8080/viewtopic.php?f=88&t=5150) about covering of woman against angel, about khadija. even if it (that narration) is true, i think, it is only against angel who is in form of a man.

it is not against angels or allah because allah knows and sees anything and angels probably can enter through cloth.

but if you see glass floor and suspect there is video/photo camera, then you should avoid that place or cover it with material.