# Do i have to wash the undergarment?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, najis

Do i have to watch my undergarments in washing machine if a little drop of urine comes on it? I was praying suddenly felt a tiny drop of urine came in my underwear, its common and i cant control it. Happens all the time. I cant be washing mt clothes in washing machine every day because of that, can i just wash it with some watee and use my clothes/undergarments to pray again? Im a male 19 years old. Thanks

Comment: Do you have only one underwear?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help] for more information about our site and model.

Comment: Related [Does dripping urine break Wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2955/11938)

Answer (score 2):

### You only need to wash the parts where there is a urine stain and then once it's washed, you can pray

---

Alqama and Aswad reported:

> أَنَّ رَجُلاً، نَزَلَ بِعَائِشَةَ فَأَصْبَحَ يَغْسِلُ ثَوْبَهُ فَقَالَتْ عَائِشَةُ إِنَّمَا كَانَ يُجْزِئُكَ إِنْ رَأَيْتَهُ أَنْ تَغْسِلَ مَكَانَهُ فَإِنْ لَمْ تَرَ نَضَحْتَ حَوْلَهُ وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُنِي أَفْرُكُهُ مِنْ ثَوْبِ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَرْكًا فَيُصَلِّي فِيهِ
>
> *A person stayed in the house of A'isha and in the morning began to wash his garment. A'isha said:* ***In case you saw it (i. e. drop of semen), it would have served the purpose (of purifying the garment) if you had simply washed that spot;*** *and in case you did not see it, it would have been enough to sprinkle water around it,* ***for when I saw that on the garment of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). I simply scraped it off and he offered prayer, while putting that on.***
>
> <sup>- [Sahih Muslim 566](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/134)</sup>

Comment: @Medi1Saif  My bad, I meant that emission of semen will require obligatory ghusl while emission of urine doesn't

Answer (score 1):

All scholars are in consensus that urine is najis (ritually impure).

So to wear clothes that you know of them having got in contact with urine (See also about the case if you prayed this way without knowing it [Is istinja' necessary for ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution/30953#30953)) while praying, you must have washed at least the parts that are najis (with water). In case of doubt -about the location of najasa- you may even need to wash the whole clothes. As Allahs the almighty says:

> And your clothing purify ([74:4](https://legacy.quran.com/74/4))

Note that to clean a najasa (a ritual impurity) you must do your best effort to take away the three attributes: odor, color and taste of this najasa (see for example in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/365) and [Ritual impurity in pants](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42575/ritual-impurity-in-pants/42577#42577)).

This means you have a couple of options:

- washing it by hand you need only soap and water, if you use much water you can even resign from using soap based on a hadith compiled by imam Ahmad in his Musnad see [here](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/1/36) in Buluggh al-Maraam.
- washing it in washing machine (as you suggested),
- washing these parts of the underwear and praying with the washed underwear or
- taking it off and praying without, there's no necessity in praying with underwear as long as your 'awrah is coated and one may even pray in one single garment. See also [Exposing awrah to the ground when praying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20205/exposing-awrah-to-the-ground-when-praying).